# fsync with raw device fd

Tags: io, filesystems, fsync

I'm confused with `fsync` + `direct IO`.

It's easy to understand the code like this:

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR, 00644);
write(fd, data, size);
fsync(fd);
```

In this case, `write()` will write the data to the page cache, and `fsync` will force all modified data in the page cache referred to by the `fd` to the disk device.

But if we open a file with `O_DIRECT` flag, like this,

```
fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_DIRECT, 00644);
write(fd, data, size);
fsync(fd);
```

In this case, `write()` will bypass the page cache, the write directly to disk device. So what will the `fsync` do, there is no dirty page in the page cache referred to by the `fd`.

And if we open a raw device, what will `fsync` do,

```
fd = open('/dev/sda', O_RDWR|O_DIRECT, 00644);
write(fd, data, size);
fsync(fd);
```

In this case, we open a raw device with `O_DIRECT`, there is no filesystem on this device. What will `sync` do here ?

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem might not implement `O_DIRECT` at all, in which case it will have no effect.

If it does implement `O_DIRECT`, then that still doesn't mean it goes to disk, it [only means it's minimally cached by the page cache](https://linux.die.net/man/2/open). It could still be cached elsewhere, even in hardware buffers.

`fsync(2)` is an explicit [contract](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fsync) between the kernel and application to persist the data such that it doesn't get lost and is guaranteed to be available to the next thing that wants to access it.

With device files, the device drivers are the ones implementing flags, including `O_DIRECT`.

Linux does use the page cache cache to cache access to block devices and does support `O_DIRECT` in order to minimize cache interaction when writing directly to a block device.

In both cases, you need `fsync(2)` or a call with an equivalent guarantee in order to be sure that the data is persistent on disk.

Comment: If I open a device ```fd = open('/dev/sda', O_RDWR|O_DIRECT, 00644)```, and write to the this device ```write(fd, data, size)```, how do I guarantee the data actually written on disk? Would ```fsync(fd)``` help in this case?

Comment: @Hao (Assuming Linux) Yes, `fsync()` would help (because it may cause devices to flush their volatile buffers) but you would have to `fsync()` AND check the return code from your `write()` AND `fsync()` for errors before assuming data is on disk. However this assumes you are the SOLE writer to the that **block device**. If you are talking about files in a filesystem that's another matter (see answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990180/what-does-it-take-to-be-durable-on-linux ).