# Use of undeclared identifier 'O_DIRECT'

Tags: c, macos

Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define __USE_GNU 1
#include <fcntl.h>


int main()
{
    int fd = open("./test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_DIRECT);

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

I use `clang -o out test.c` and get the following result:

```
test.c:14:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'O_DIRECT'
    int fd = open("./test.txt", O_WRONLY|O_DIRECT);
```

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: MacOS does not implement `O_DIRECT`.  You will need to make substantial changes to the larger program.  [This old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307055)  suggests the existence of an `fcntl` opcode called `F_NOCACHE` which is more-or-less equivalent, but the documentation it refers to has been removed from Apple's website, so that's as much detail as I can give you.

Comment: I can also tell you that `#define _GNU_SOURCE` has no effect on MacOS, and that _even on Linux_ it only has an effect if you define it _before_ including any system headers at all, and that `#define __USE_GNU` in application code provokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you zwol.  
You solved all my confuse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To sum up

For LINUX, the `O_DIRECT` flag has to be included. For Mac OSX, `O_DIRECT` is not available. Instead, `fcntl(fd, F_NOCACHE, 1)` looks to be the canonical solution where fd is the file descriptor of the file. For Windows, there is a flag called `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` as the counterpart in Windows of `O_DIRECT`

[Reference here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Direct-IO)

Answer (score 0):

With this snippet it is impossible to tell what you are trying to do, but in general do not use nonstandard stuff in applications intended to be portable.

The portable way to accomplish your task is *probably* `fsync`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I just want to do something between `open` and `close`. Now I have known about the difference between Mac&Linux. Thank you.